# Modal window not closed in after submitting the Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to make this work but the submit button is not working at all.

Whenever I click the submit buttons,the modal window did not close.

The bootstrap modal window I am using is:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="like_Modal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm sr_popup">
        <div class="modal-content sr_popup_content">
            <div class="modal-header sr_pop_heading">
                <button class="close sr_popup_close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    type="button">&times;</button>
                <p class="modal-title sr_title">Save Likes to Favorites</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="favForm">
                    <div class="fm_panel">
                        <label class="formLabel">Name</label> <input class="form-control"
                            name="docTitle" type="text" value="{{documentTitle}}"
                            ng-maxlength="150" maxlength="150" required
                            ng-model="documentTitle"> <span
                            ng-show="favForm.docTitle.$error.required" style="color: red;">
                            The name is required.</span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-default sr-submit-button" type="submit"
                        ng-click="saveBookmark(documentTitle, documentUrl);"
                        ng-disabled="!favForm.$valid">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link:

```
<a  href="" id="kb_rslts_img_add_to_like_{{$index}}" ng-click="saveTolikes(x.documenttitle, x.url);" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

Comment: where's your angular code and can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

### Following example in jquery, it will be helpful for you

```js
$(function(){
   $('#im_modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
 <div id="im_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Image" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-footer">
            <a type="button" class="btn pull-left"  data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">OK</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the modal by using the following line of code.

```
 $('#like_Modal').modal('hide');
```